# How to replicate a custom button/VF in Lightning

Tags: visualforce, custom-button, lightning-design-system

We migrated to Lightning and there is a custom button on the Opportunity page that loads a Visualforce page and I need to get it replicated to work in Lightning. I am not a developer nor do I have one available to me so I am looking for guidance on how to get this or similar functionality working in Lightning. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What happens when you push this button now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visualforce page and custom buttons that launch Visualforce are completely supported in Lighting Experience.

So your existing code should work as it is. However, the look and feel and the design of the page would resemble classic and might not fit well into the lightning experience UI.

There is an easy way to make sure your Visualforce page uses the Lightning Design system, so your page works well within the lightning experience. This can be achieved by following instructions in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/vf_dev_best_practices_slds_apply.htm).

Make sure to apply SLDS styles by using `<apex:slds />` as shown below

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">

 <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
 <apex:slds />

<!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
<div class="slds-scope">
```

I would try the above technique in the sandbox and see if this works fine! There are some Visualforce tags that might not work, so making changes and testing them in the sandbox would be a good first step.

**Update**

There is also [Lightning Experience Configuration Converter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lcc_overview.htm&type=5) that can covert your [buttons, links, actions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lcc_javascript_buttons_overview.htm&type=5) and [VF automatically](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.lcc_visualforce_apply_stylesheets.htm&type=5&language=en_US) without you having to deal with the code.

Comment: I do see a way to automatically apply the LSS using the Lightning Config converter app so i don't have to touch the code myself which I believe is bascially what your solution would entail doing myself. The page looks basically like it did previously (which wasn't very nice to begin with really, LOL). –